# Iterate through Enum and extract values

Tags: elixir

```
list_of_comboboxes=[
{"option", [{"value", ""}, {"selected", "selected"}], ["Select Color"]}, 
{"option", [{"value", "White"}, {"data", "White"}], ["White"]},
{"option", [{"value", "Red"}, {"data", "Red"}], ["Red"]},
{"option", [{"value", "Black"}, {"data", "Black"}], ["Black"]}
]
```

Need to extract all the values in the above Enum to a list

Comment: It would be nice to see what you have tried before you posted it here.

Comment: I need to extract the values/ data attributes, have tried Enum.into and failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just out of curiosity:

```rb
list_of_comboboxes
|> Enum.map(fn {"option", list, _} ->
     Enum.map(list, fn {k, v} -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end)[:value]
   end)
#⇒ ["", "White", "Red", "Black"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do this using pattern matching, `for`, and `List.keyfind/3`:

```
iex(1)> list_of_comboboxes=[
...(1)>   {"option", [{"value", ""}, {"selected", "selected"}], ["Select Color"]},
...(1)>   {"option", [{"value", "White"}, {"data", "White"}], ["White"]},
...(1)>   {"option", [{"value", "Red"}, {"data", "Red"}], ["Red"]},
...(1)>   {"option", [{"value", "Black"}, {"data", "Black"}], ["Black"]}
...(1)> ]
iex(2)> for {_, list, _} <- list_of_comboboxes,
...(2)>     {"value", value} = List.keyfind(list, "value", 0),
...(2)>     do: value
["", "White", "Red", "Black"]
```

This will work even if `{"value", value}` is not the first item of the list.

Comment: This is the best and most clea answer. If you would have Keyword list, it would be easier to get the value, but this way you don't depend on the order and it's quite efficient, because you apply guard clause on `for`.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_of_comboboxes |>
Enum.map( fn ({_, [{_, x}, {_, _}], [_]}) -> 
          x end )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity #2:

```rb
defmodule M do
  def extract({"option", [{"value", value} | _], _}), do: value
end
Enum.map(list_of_comboboxes, &M.extract/1)
#⇒ ["", "White", "Red", "Black"]
```

This might look worse, but in fact it gives more flexibility: one might adjust the implementation details (`M.extract/1`) leaving the integration code (`Enum.map`) intact.

That way the code stays more modular. E.g. one might use the `List.keyfind/3` proposed by @Dogbert in `M.extract/1` for better interoperability, while the main code stays as it was.